# Error when trying to install Productivity Power Tools for Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, productivity-power-tools

I have tried on two different machines, and tried the download several times, but whenever I try and install the Productivity Power Tools extension in VS 2010 Premium (10.0.30139.1 RTMRel), I get the error "The file is not a valid VSIX package."  A search reveals only one or two other people have ever experienced this issue.  How can I go about diagnosing this issue?

EDIT:  In response to Aaron's suggestion below, I ran the code with the following result:

```
at MS.Internal.IO.Zip.ZipIOLocalFileDataDescriptor.ParseRecord(BinaryReader reader, Int64 compressedSizeFromCentralDir, Int64 uncompressedSizeFromCentralDir, UInt32 crc32FromCentralDir, UInt16 versionNeededToExtract)
at MS.Internal.IO.Zip.ZipIOLocalFileBlock.ParseRecord(BinaryReader reader, String fileName, Int64 position, ZipIOCentralDirectoryBlock centralDir, ZipIOCentralDirectoryFileHeader centralDirFileHeader)
at MS.Internal.IO.Zip.ZipIOLocalFileBlock.SeekableLoad(ZipIOBlockManager blockManager, String fileName)
at MS.Internal.IO.Zip.ZipIOBlockManager.LoadLocalFileBlock(String zipFileName)
at MS.Internal.IO.Zip.ZipArchive.GetFile(String zipFileName)
at MS.Internal.IO.Zip.ZipArchive.GetFiles()
at System.IO.Packaging.ZipPackage.ContentTypeHelper..ctor(ZipArchive zipArchive, IgnoredItemHelper ignoredItemHelper)
at System.IO.Packaging.ZipPackage..ctor(Stream s, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Boolean streaming)
at System.IO.Packaging.Package.Open(Stream stream, FileMode packageMode, FileAccess packageAccess, Boolean streaming)
at System.IO.Packaging.Package.Open(Stream stream, FileMode packageMode, FileAccess packageAccess)
at VSIXReadTest.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\\Development\\WebSockets\\PowerTools\\Program.cs:line 17
```

I have downloaded the file several times, each with the same result, suggesting to me that there is something different or wrong with my file system or the `Packaging` library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm a developer on the team that wrote the VSIX/Extension Manager for Visual Studio 2010, so perhaps I can help out here. A VSIX file is an OPC container (basically a zip file with a few extra constraints). As you might expect, we use the Managed OPC API's to open the file (i.e. the System.IO.Packaging namespace in .NET). This error message should only occur if the call to ZipPackage.Open fails.

Could you try compiling the following code into a C# console application (targetting .NET 4.0) on your machine and seeing what the results are? You'll need to also add an assembly reference to WindowsBase. If there is a bug here, we'd certainly like to know more about it!

```
namespace VSIXReadTest
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.IO;
    using System.IO.Packaging;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                const string PathToVsixFile = @"PutPathHere!!!";
                using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(PathToVsixFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                {
                    Package vsixPackage = ZipPackage.Open(stream, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                StringBuilder errorMessage = new StringBuilder();
                do
                {
                    errorMessage.Append(ex.GetType().Name);
                    errorMessage.Append(": ");
                    errorMessage.AppendLine(ex.Message);
                    errorMessage.AppendLine(ex.StackTrace);
                    ex = ex.InnerException;
                } while (ex != null);

                Console.WriteLine(errorMessage.ToString());
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Press a key to exit...");
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Aaron.  This code throws a *FileFormatException: File contains corrupted data*.  I have added the stack trace to my question.

Comment: Can you verify that you don't have a corrupted download somehow? I'm seeing that the current version of ProPowerTools.vsix (version 10.0.20318.14) has a MD5 checksum of cdd55a9d8ac33a69217c9d79a17690ac. You can use the FCIV tool from Microsoft to get the checksum on your machine. http://bit.ly/fCSWdy

Comment: OK, the hash was different, so I deleted the .visx and downloaded it again, and the hash is now the same and it works.  This is very strange because I previously downloaded the file several times, even on two different machines, with the same error.  Maybe our internet cache was interfering or something?

Answer (score 0):

A .VSIX file is in fact a .ZIP file undercovers. Try to rename it and see what you have inside. Maybe it's just a corrupted download issue? I have tried this link http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef/ myself and it seems to work fine.

Comment: The file opens OK when I rename it, and I can examine the contents.  I've tried several downloads with the same result.  This is a really funny issue.

Comment: @ProfK - have you tried to double-click on the .vsix? is it doing the same thing? From my registry (HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VisualStudio.Launcher.vsix\Shell\Open\Command), .vsix are handled by this program:  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\MSEnv\VSLauncher.exe" "%1", maybe there is a problem with it? maybe you could try to repair VS 2010

Comment: thanks, but the installer program seems fine - I've installed other extensions with it recently, after I noticed the problem with the Power Tools.